# PHP, mysql memory leak

Tags: php, mysql, memory-leaks, pdo, mysqli

Faced with a problem, I can not find a memory leak when working with a database. The script takes a large data from database and therefore the memory leak critical. This problem occurs when working with mysqli, mysql or PDO.
Here is test code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Connection error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($link, 'coolstat.my') or die ('Can\'t use coolstat.my: ' . mysql_error());


for($ii=0; $ii<20000; $ii+=1000){
    $sql= "SELECT `codes_data`.* FROM `codes_data` INNER JOIN codes ON codes.siteid= 20     AND codes.codeid=codes_data.codeid LIMIT ".$ii.", ".($ii+1000)."";
    ///

    $data= array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))){
        $data[]= $row;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    unset($result);
    unset($data);
    echo "Memory get_data usage: ".convert_memory_val(memory_get_peak_usage(true))."<br />\n";
}
mysqli_close($link);


function convert_memory_val($size){
    $unit = array('b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb');
    return @round($size / pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . ' ' . $unit[$i];
}
```

It output:

```
Memory get_data usage: 3.25 mb
Memory get_data usage: 6 mb
Memory get_data usage: 9 mb
Memory get_data usage: 11.75 mb
Memory get_data usage: 14.75 mb
Memory get_data usage: 17.75 mb
Memory get_data usage: 20.5 mb
Memory get_data usage: 23.5 mb
Memory get_data usage: 26.5 mb
Memory get_data usage: 29.5 mb
Memory get_data usage: 32.25 mb
Memory get_data usage: 35.25 mb
Memory get_data usage: 38.25 mb
Memory get_data usage: 41.25 mb
Memory get_data usage: 44 mb
Memory get_data usage: 47 mb
Memory get_data usage: 50 mb
Memory get_data usage: 53 mb
Memory get_data usage: 56 mb
Memory get_data usage: 58.75 mb
```

Comment: not the subject but you need to replace mysql_error by mysqli_error($link).

Comment: You have no control over how PHP does **garbage collection**. You cannot measure 'memory leaks' this way! See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. You are not new here, you should already know the difference between a comment and an answer.

Comment: it's not a production script, just a quick copy paste

Comment: But can I accelerate this, or clean memory manually?

Comment: No you cannot not. Even if you set all references to a object to null, you have no control over when the garbage collector will run.

Comment: Actually you can change the memory_limit setting to a lower value, which "could" force the use of the garbage collector, but it doesn't matter; as long as the memory used is way lower than your memory_limit setting (default is 128M in Windows PHP5.4), the GC should not be invoked.

Comment: In this case I can't change memory limit

Comment: But script overflow memory and I get Error. If GC must work in this case, this doesn't happen.

Comment: which platform? which version of PHP exactly?

Comment: @JvdBerg actually this is not true - you *can* manually collect the garbage. see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in the Limit clause: the 2nd number should be a constant, for ex. 1000. With what you have the queries will be

```
LIMIT 0, 1000
LIMIT 1000, 2000
LIMIT 2000, 3000
...
```

This is not pagination, you fetch data in increasing chunks that also overlap. So the increase in memory use is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> When the [garbage collector](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php) is turned on, the cycle-finding algorithm as described above is executed whenever the root buffer runs full. The root buffer has a fixed size of 10,000 possible roots [...]
>  It is also possible to force the collection of cycles even if the possible root buffer is not full yet. For this, you can use the [gc_collect_cycles()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) function. This function will return how many cycles were collected by the algorithm.

so .. just try to [force garbage collection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) at the end of your loop body:

```
for ($ii = 0; $ii < 20000; $ii += 1000) {
    // ...

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    unset($result);
    unset($data);
    echo "Memory before GC run: ".convert_memory_val(memory_get_peak_usage(true))."<br />\n";

    $n = gc_collect_cycles();
    echo "GC collected $n garbage cycles<br />\n";
    echo "Memory after GC run: ".convert_memory_val(memory_get_peak_usage(true))."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: @ВладФедосов nevertheless .. this is how you manually free memory in long running scripts. The answer may help others to learn.